# Remove a tile from a scene with GDScript in Godot

Tags: tiles, godot, scene

How do I remove a tile from a scene programmatically? I have tried the following to no avail:

```
func _physics_process(_delta):

    ...

    velocity = move_and_slide(velocity, Vector2.UP)

    for i in get_slide_count():
        var collision = get_slide_collision(i)
        if collision.collider.name == "MysteryBox":
            remove_tile(collision.position)

func remove_tile(position):
    var tilemap= get_parent().get_node("Tilesets/MysteryBox")
    tilemap.set_cell(position.x, position.y, -1)
```

I can detect the MysteryBox when the player collides with it, but the remove function is not removing the tile the player touched from the scene. Thanks in advance!
Godot version 3.4.2

Comment: Does calling `tilemap.get_cell(position.x, position.y)` inside `remove_tile` return the tile you are expecting to modify? I recall different coordinate behavior for `set_cell` vs `set_cellv` ... could you be pointing it at something other than what you intend?

Comment: It's returning INVALID_CELL... can you suggest an approach for what I want to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert the position from global coordinates (which is what you get in a `KinematicCollision` or `KinematicCollision2D` such as the one returned by `get_slide_collision`) to the coordinates of the `TileMap`.

What I said above can be accomplished like this:

```
var local_position:Vector2 = tilemap.to_local(position)
```

However, you also want the position in tiles. Not pixels. Which you could do using the size of a cell:

```
var local_position:Vector2 = tilemap.to_local(position)
var cell_position:Vector2 = local_position/tilemap.cell_size
```

Or alternatively yet, do it like this:

```
var local_position:Vector2 = tilemap.to_local(position)
var cell_position:Vector2 = tilemap.world_to_map(local_position)
```

And now you know what `world_to_map` does and why you would want to use it. There is also a `map_to_world` that does the opposite transformation.

---

If I understand correctly you want to remove the tile that your `KinematicBody2D` collided with. So you are taking the position of the collision. However, the position of the collision is not inside the tile.

To fix that, you can offset the position in the opposite direction of the normal of the collision (i.e. inwards into whatever it collided with):

```
var tilemap:TileMap = collision.collider as TileMap
var local_position:Vector2 = tilemap.to_local(collision.position)
var cell_position:Vector2 = tilemap.world_to_map(local_position)
cell_position -= collision.normal
```

Then `cell_position` should be inside the correct tile.

Comment: I am getting "Parser Error: The assigned value doesn't have a set type; the variable type can't be inferred." from your second code example. Taking the colons out, the code runs but still returns INVALID_CELL.

Comment: @KeithR.Davis I can tell you that `local_position` and `cell_position` should be `Vector2`, you can either specify it (i.e. example `local_position:Vector2 = …`) or you can remove the `:` which leaves the variable as variant. Turns out it could not figure out the type, because it didn't know the `Node` from `get_node` is a `TileMap`. You could do `var tilemap= get_parent().get_node("Tilesets/MysteryBox") as TileMap` is you wish. About `INVALID_CELL`, it means there is no tile there, are you sure there is one? Edit: I think I see what it is, I'll update the answer.

Comment: Had to subtract -1 from the cell_position.y to get the tile above the player and then it worked!

Comment: @KeithR.Davis That is the idea, except you are now assuming that the collision is always in that direction. There is a general solution. Edit: added to the answer.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! Working great!